# calling EJB3 on Glassfish 4.1 txlogdir is null

Tags: transactions, java-ee-7, glassfish-4.1

let's say I have a

```
@Stateless @LocalBean SomeEJB
```

referencing WebService Methods with `@TransactionAttribute(value=TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)` annotation.
Now, calling this Method in war (injected with @EJB) for the first time gives me his error:

```
Information:   Missing required extension methods detected on 'javax.transaction.TransactionManager' implementation 'com.sun.enterprise.transaction.TransactionManagerHelper':
getTxLogLocation

Information:   txlogdir isnull
Warnung:   A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB SomeEJB, method: public java.util.List service.application.SomeEJB.findPeopleByString(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
Warnung:   javax.ejb.EJBException
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.processSystemException(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:748)
....
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:277)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.tx.at.internal.WSATGatewayRM.setTxLogDirs(WSATGatewayRM.java:430)
```

After that, the method is correctly called and gives right information until I restart glassfish.
May somebody got a hint what to look for?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug has been marked as fixed, but it is more an workaround. Like explained here:
https://java.net/jira/browse/WSIT-1500
You have to deploy wstx-services.war before your application...